# Sun ras format in ArcGIS 10.3 for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, export, arcgis-10.3

I have some data stored in sun ras data. I found several pages that state this format is supported. e.g. http://support.esri.com/fr/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/26784
I'm using version 10.3, which is not listed there, but I was guessing that if it was supported on earlier versions, it probably still is. 
So I want to display the data using ArcMap. But when I want to add the data to my layer, they do not appear in the database where I stored them. In the "Add Data" window it says it will only show files of the type "datasets, layers and results", but in the pulldown menu I cannot choose an option that says "display all formats". 
Any ideas on how to proceed?

Comment: For what little it's worth, the KB article you link to lists that format under a particular heading: "Additional data types are supported by way of importers in ArcInfo." To me, this implies with ArcInfo (now Advanced) you had access to an import tool that could handle the format - not that you could simply use the Add Data button. That said, [newer help files](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//018m00000002000000) just mention it as 'supported', without need for even Data Interoperability. Which extension is it using? I found three - maybe it isn't recognizing one?

Comment: It's using the extension "ras". I wanted to try sun an sunras aswell but the program I'm using that gives out the raster file doesn't let me change to sun or sunras.. :-(

Comment: In theory the internal file format would be the same regardless of extension, or at least that's possible. You could always try manually renaming the file to change the extension just to see.

Answer (score -1):

Check whether your ArcGIS installation is current on patches.

I recollect that there was a patched bug that might be causing the condition you have observed.

Comment: It would be very helpful providing a link to that bug;)

Comment: Yes I agree with Aaron, I don't understand what you mean/where I should check this !?